# New USB-C / Thunderbolt C features

Tags: gpu, thunderbolt, usb-c

A lot of new systems are going to be coming out with USB-C / Thunderbolt which allows you to use pci-e bus over it.  Specifically using an external GPU over USB-C, for example the [Razer Blade Stealth / Razer Core](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-systems/razer-blade-stealth?src=pgm.95498400&utm_source=email&utm_campaign=jointcesUS&utm_medium=edm_US).

Since this is a new feature I am assuming we won't have support right away. Does anyone know if this is supported and if it is what is the performance like?

Comment: Yet another down vote with no reason as to why.

Comment: I personally think it's a very interesting question, but I can't find any information for ANY platform, Ubuntu or otherwise. From the link you provided, "The Razer Core is the world’s first true plug and play Thunderbolt™ 3 (USB-C) external graphics enclosure." My best guess is that it'll take time for this idea to catch on and be implemented.

Comment: May be because USB Type-C is just the connector or plug. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Type-C . Then you are into which technology whether USB3.1 Gen 1 (old USB3) or or USB3.1 Gen2 or the new USB standard for faster connections. And Intel Thunderbolt 3 now uses the USB-C connector and is compatible with USB3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable USB type C connectors on 15.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/714169/how-can-i-enable-usb-type-c-connectors-on-15-10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well since it has been awhile I figured I would post the results that have been coming out on this.

So far some one running Arch on an XPS 13 and using the Razer Core has gotten an Nvidia 970 to run.

You can read more here for anyone who is interested.

[image]
https://www.reddit.com/r/razer/comments/4xwlt6/razer_core_gtx_970_on_xps_13_9350_arch_linux/