# USB Type C battery charge not working on Lenovo Thinkpad 25 on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: usb, power-management, lenovo, thinkpad

My Lenovo Thinkpad 25 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 is not receiving power via the USB Type C port. Is this a driver issue? Or does Ubuntu not support USB Type C charging of a laptop?

Note: My Lenovo Thinkpad 25 could charge via the USB Type C from an external power pack (via the Type C USB) when I was still using Windows 10. It only stopped charging via Type C after I wiped Windows (g'bye) and loaded Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable USB type C connectors on 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714169/how-can-i-enable-usb-type-c-connectors-on-15-10)

Comment: Thanks, I saw that post, but it is not the same issue.

Comment: I hope we hear an answer on this. My setup:  Thinkpad x370, latest ubuntu. Usbc does not work to charge. Also worked with Windows but not after I wiped it.

Comment: I updated to 17.10 in hopes there would be a fix, but nope.

Comment: Issue still remains in 18.01, serious bummer.